# Chrome's Dev Tools Audit pass lists styles only added by jQuery

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

The audit function of Chrome Dev Tools lists all CSS rules that it can' find in the HTML but that includes style declarations that are only added by jQuery's .addClass(). So if you removed all the styles that Audit said weren't being used,  your page would break.

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Page Performance Audit is very simple and can't possibly cover all states that your complex web page can be in. "Remove unused CSS rules" is a suggestion for you that something *might* need optimization. Please note that even google page has ~60% of rules that are unused (according to the audit report).

[image: Web Page Performance Audit results for google.pl]